# Addition of anodes and cathodes in electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I am doing a research on the production of hypochlorite through an electrochemical cell using a brine feed. I know that using using an undivided cell would allow for the chlorine atoms that was oxidised at the anode to react with the $\ce{OH-}$ ions in the solution. However, I was just wondering what the addition of more anodes and electrodes would do to the product?

Comment: You might find NOTE ON THE ELECTROLYTIC PREPARATION OF
DILUTE SODIUM HYPOCHLORITE SOLUTIONS
(DAKIN'S SOLUTION), *J. Biol. Chem.*, **1919**, * 37*, 519-523 helpful.